# How to create a multilevel dataframe from uneven-layer dictionary?

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dictionary:

```
dic = {'key': 1, 'detail': {'name': 'Ken', 'sex': 'M', 'location': {'lat': 10, 'lng': 20}, 'family': {'sister': {'name': 'Ann', 'location': {'lat': 30, 'lng': 40}}}}}
```

How can I get the following data frame?

[image]

Comment: If that's the desired output of the dataframe, with that many column level, it's going to be very difficult to use. The better option is `df = pd.json_normalize(dic)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `json_normalize()`+`pd.MultiIndex.from_frame()`+`'columns'` attribute:

```
df=pd.json_normalize(dic)
idx=pd.DataFrame(df.columns.str.split('.',expand=True).tolist()).fillna('')
df.columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(idx,names=[None]*len(idx.columns))
```

output of `df`:

[image]

OR

but it will show `NaN` in columns:

```
df=pd.json_normalize(dic)
df.columns=df.columns.str.split('.',expand=True)
```

output of `df`:

[image]

Comment: For the second case, doing `df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([tuple(i  if pd.notna(i) else '' for i in v) for v in df.columns])` will get rid of `NaN`